# How can I generate a two separate columns list of unique “combos”?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, unique

desired output:

| E | F |
| --- | --- |
| red | 2016 |
| red | 2020 |
| black | 2018 |

example:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| color |  | year |
| red |  | 2016 |
| red |  | 2020 |
| black |  | 2018 |
| red |  | 2016 |
| red |  | 2020 |

Comment: Please choose one, they are different.  Even in Excel it depends on your version.

Comment: ^^^^ But if your version of Excel supports it, use `UNIQUE`. And use `UNIQUE` in Sheets. Which is what it seems you're *actually* using based on previous questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In sheets:

```
=UNIQUE({A2:A,C2:C})
```

[image]

which will error in Excel.

Answer (score 1):

if the previous answer won't work use:

```
=UNIQUE({A2:A\C2:C})
```